# Down voted after reputation cap was reached

Tags: discussion, reputation, down-votes, up-votes

Let's assume you reached the reputation cap, and you then receive some up-votes, which are not counted. If you get down-voted, your reputation is lowered by 2 points.

Is this right to lose reputation when you have earned more than 200 points?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

May be not so right, but if you get another upvote, you will get +2 back.

Comment: But what if you don't get, you will end with 198, despite of having all this upvotes after 200

Comment: @Stecya, yeah, that's life!

Comment: @stecya: Yeah, I hate when my reputation score is something other than a round number, too. My psychiatrist tells me it doesn't really matter though.

Comment: @Cody you could down vote 48 posts. Is 150 round enough for you? :P

Answer (score 0):

Down-votes have still the same effect, even if you reached the reputation cap. There is not difference between being down-voted before reaching the reputation cap, and after reaching it.

Comment: Unless you get downvoted all the way to 1 rep and then they'll stop dropping your rep further.  :)  But if you manage all that then you deserve a custom badge.

Comment: @Daniel DiPaolo Would not "Master of disaster" be the right name for such badge?

Answer (score 0):

Go to stackoverflow.com/reputation

Check you actual vs calculated and recalculate to get your 2 points back. Of course, it could go lower ifcquestions are migrated etc